# Is it possible to disable JS in RoR project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, w3m

New to rails. Was working on chapter 2 of [railsTutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app).

I was pair programming with someone who only uses text based browser [w3m](http://w3m.sourceforge.net/). So once we created user resource, we created a new user and tried deleting it but couldn't. I could do it on my Chrome browser though, so thought this may be issue with JS or so.

How do we resolve this?

Comment: i must be issue with turbolinks. you are unable to click on the delete link ?

Comment: Yes. Also can successfully delete it from Chrome too.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/77-destroy-without-javascript

Comment: @Saqib really out of date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails relies on javascript for links to http `DELETE` actions.

```
link_to "Delete Thing", thing_path(@thing), method: :delete
```

Generates a link with a `data-method` attribute. The [Rails UJS driver](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) then catches the click and turns it into into an AJAX HTTP `DELETE` request.

> `method:` symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an
>   HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the
>   HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation
>   in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can
>   follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete,
>   :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the
>   request will fall back to using GET. If href: '#' is used and the user
>   has JavaScript disabled clicking the link will have no effect. If you
>   are relying on the POST behavior, you should check for it in your
>   controller's action by using the request object's methods for post?,
>   delete?, patch?, or put?.
>   http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

### Added:

The whole reason we do this is that Rails is built around restful interfaces using the full range of HTTP methods; `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE`, `PUT`, `PATCH`. But some browsers can only send `GET` & `POST` requests and HTML does not define links which perform other actions than `GET`.

If no javascript is a requirement you can create a form to send requests other than `GET`:

```
<%= form_for @thing, method: :delete do |f| %>
   <%= f.submit 'Delete thing' %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this form uses `method="post"` for compatability. Rails adds a special hidden input to the resulting form:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" />
```

Which Rails uses to fake the extended set of HTTP methods (`DELETE`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, etc).

Comment: Thanks. Will look into this. I was aware that the same line of code would be causing this.

Comment: Added an explanation on how to create delete buttons that work without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Turbolinks` with your Rails(4) application, it's easy! Just do this:

- Remove the `gem 'turbolinks'` line from your `Gemfile`
- Remove the `//=require turbolinks` from your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`
- Remove the two `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` hash key/value pairs
  from your `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: Once I do this, would the destroy would go through?

Comment: yup all the links will work fine. make sure to restart you server and browser

Comment: Downvoted. Turbolinks has nothing to do with your issue with handling delete requests. The Rails UJS driver (jquery-rails) is totally independent from Turbolinks, which simply speeds browsing by doing partial replacement. https://github.com/rails/turbolinks